# Not all paths return a value in Public ActionResult , I used Exception

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc

Basically when i do this

```
public ActionResult ValidateLogin()
{
    return View();
}
```

This works fine now When i use say a try catch block in this case and i do something like return `RedirectToAction("Dashboard");` in try catch blocks, i am also expecting that it should check the designation, before it redirects the user to the main page, it fires and Error like not all paths return a value.

My source code looks like this

```
public ActionResult ValidateLogin(UserAuthClass auth)
{
    string constring = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-9CM4N5S\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MVCLogintestDB;Integrated Security=True";
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        con.Open();

        string query = "select * from [MVCLogintestDB].[dbo].[users_table] where username = @username and password= @password and designation = @designation";
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username",auth.username);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", auth.password);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("designation", auth.designation);

            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            try
            {
                da.Fill(dt);
                if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (auth.designation == "Admin")
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("AdminDashboard");
                    }
                    else if (auth.designation == "Security")
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("SecurityDashboard");
                    }
                    else if (auth.designation == "Visitor")
                    {
                        return RedirectToAction("VisitorDashboard");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    return RedirectToAction("WrongPasswordArea");
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to understand what is the wrong thing I appear to be missing here?

Comment: When `dt.Rows.Count > 0` is true, and the `auth.designation` is neither _"Admin"_ nor _"Security"_ nor _"Visitor"_, then your current code doesn't return anything. This is probably what the compiler is complaining about.

Comment: @bassfader, i dont understand

Comment: You are missing a `return` statement for the case that `dt.Rows.Count > 0` and `auth.designation` is something else than _"Admin"_, _"Security"_ or _"Visitor"_. Your code doesn't have a `return` statement for all possible code paths in your method. For example what do you want to do when `auth.designation` is something else, like _"Guest"_?

Comment: Looks like you're confusing business and presentation logic. As Jerry says in his answer, you must redirect to an action and present an error to the user, the try-catch introduces another code path which doesn't return a view. This is why it's good to follow an MVC pattern to add that abstraction and understand clearly where the Controller's responsibilities start and end.

Comment: @bassfader, Thanks bro, You did good, i am Most grateful, but Jerry got it correctly. works exactly as i wanted it

Comment: As a side note: 1) Never rethrow an exception using `throw ex;` because this way you lose your stacktrace and you don't know anymore where the exception originated. Just use `throw;`. 2) A catch statement which is just rethrowing the exception is useless as the result is the same as if you hadn't caught the exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a default return outside of your using block.
Something like this

```
return RedirectToAction("Login");
```

When all scenarios fail, return the user to the Login page or whatever your Login page is called.

Comment: outside of the using(SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring)) You mean? if yes , i did it and i dont see any error so far

Comment: I'd strongly advise against such a default behaviour, as this probably will only hide potential future errors. For example when a new possible `designation` value is introduced, but the if-statemtents above are not adjusted accordingly, then this will "silently fail" and just redirect to the login page.

Comment: @Jerry, Thanks a bunch, works as i expected, what return RedirectAction("Login") can do.

Answer (score 1):

Do a refactor on your `if-else-if` logic. I implemented a simpler version and the result is your error is gone.

You will have to adapt, as I did to test this in a quick environment. But just go to the guts, the `if-else-if`, and make it more logical. Again no error about missing returns in the code bellow.

```cs
public string ValidateLogin(string auth)
{
    using (new NoDispose())
    {
        using (new NoDispose())
        {
            try
            {
                int dtRowsCount = 10;
                string authDesignation = "";
                if (dtRowsCount <= 0)
                    return "WrongPasswordArea";
                switch (authDesignation)
                {
                    case "Admin":
                        return "AdminDashboard";
                    case "Security":
                        return "SecurityDashboard";
                    case "SecurityDashboard":
                        return "SecurityDashboard";
                    case "Visitor":
                    default:
                        return "VisitorDashboard";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*Disclaimer. I do not claim that the logic implemented above does exactly what the previous did, nor that it conforms to your requirements.*

## Using chains

And btw, you can chain `using` statements in the following manner.

```cs
using (var a = new NoDispose())
using (var b = new NoDispose())
{
    // both a and b are available in here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a return in your catch. I think this would be better for you to use rather than returning outside of your using block because from the return in your using you can start to show errors from this return instead of a general return outside that looks like nothing happened.